# HOW and WHY does blushing occur when one is embarrassed? Linked to fight or flight primal instincts?

Tags: coloration-discoloration, social-anthropology, cheeks, fight-or-flight, flush-face-body

Blushing -- that thing that happens when you get your first kiss or something embarrassing happens and the spotlight is on you -- ***WHAT* is it exactly? And *HOW* does it happen? And *WHY* does it happen?**

***HOW?***
We know when it happens, but what is the **physiological cause** of blushing?

- How does our body rush *blood to our cheeks (specifically)*? Is our
  body really blushing everywhere, but is it because our cheeks are so
  thin that cheek skin is more easily to pink up?
- *What is the physiological difference between blushing and flushing?* Like a blushed face and a flushed face? Is it because flushing is caused my physical stress of the body, where blushing is caused by emotional stress, and the body has different reactions that somehow look different?

**WHY?**
Most the time our body seems to react due to a physical situation, but blushing  seems like a social response that is triggered by a form of social anxiety.

- ***Is blushing a part of the fight or flight mechanism?***  *Does/Did blushing serve social or physiological benefits in a Fight or Flight scenario or was it just the results of being in a fight or flight situation?*

  - Benefits?: Is there a primal instinctive benefit that humans once had of turning red in the face in a dangerous or intense situation? Did blushing somehow scare off predators? Or it attracted a mate more in a romantic setting?
  - Result?: Whatever the reason for the fight or flight scenario, is blushing the result of being in a stressed environment? Like does the rush of blood to our brain rams up our metabolism to run?

Comment: The way to get your old questions back in view and answered is to offer a bounty. Editing tags unnecessarily just pushes your questions to the top at the expense of new questions.

Comment: This question may actually be more suited to [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com)